# Display crumble path with ember

Tags: ember.js, breadcrumbs, ember-router

I want to display a crumble path with Ember. How can I iterate through the current path?

In my opinion there are two approaches:

***The ember-way***

*EDIT: see my answer below*

I keep this question up-to-date with the current status of displaying breadcrumbs. You can browse through the revisions of this question to see the history.

There are a couple of goals here:

1. Listen on route change
2. Finding current route
3. displaying list of the current route
4. display working links to the steps in the route

**Controller**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['breadcrumbs'],
    currentPathDidChange: function() {
        path = this.get('currentPath');
        console.log('path changed to: ', path);
        this.get('controllers.breadcrumbs').set('content',this.get('target.router.currentHandlerInfos'));
    }.observes('currentPath')
});
App.BreadcrumbsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});
```

**Router**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('breadcrumbs', {
            outlet: 'breadcrumbs',
            into: 'application',
            controller: this.controllerFor('breadcrumbs')
        });
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
{{! application template }}
<div class="clearfix" id="content">
    {{outlet "breadcrumbs"}}
    {{outlet}}
</div>

{{! breadcrumbs template }}
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  {{#each link in content}}
    <li>
      <a {{bindAttr href="link.name"}}>{{link.name}}</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The current problems to tackle are:

- When I go to the URL: `#/websites/8/pages/1` the output for the breadcrumbs is: (I removed all the script-tag placeholders

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li>
    <a href="application" data-bindattr-34="34">application</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
  <li>
    <a href="sites" data-bindattr-35="35">sites</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="site" data-bindattr-36="36">site</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="pages" data-bindattr-37="37">pages</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="page" data-bindattr-38="38">page</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="page.index" data-bindattr-39="39">page.index</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- The URL's should be a valid route
- The menu is now hardcoded with `{{#linkTo}}` to the routes, I tried to make that dynamic, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/ydTWZ/) but a `transitionTo` doesn't trigger the `currentPath`-observer

***The other way***

Most is the same as above, but there are a couple of differences. The breadcrumbs are made by looping over `location.hash` instead of getting it from the Router.

The **ApplicationController** becomes:

```
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['breadcrumbs'],
    hashChangeOccured: function(context) {
        var loc = context.split('/');
        var path = [];
        var prev;
        loc.forEach(function(it) {
            if (typeof prev === 'undefined') prev = it;
            else prev += ('/'+it)
            path.push(Em.Object.create({ href: prev, name: it }));
        });
        this.get('controllers.breadcrumbs').set('content',path)
    }
});
ready : function() {
    $(window).on('hashchange',function() {
        Ember.Instrumentation.instrument("hash.changeOccured", location.hash);
    });
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
}
```

We need to subscribe the custom handler in the **ApplicationRoute**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("hash.changeOccured", {
            before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
                controller.send('hashChangeOccured', payload);
            },
            after: function() {}
        });
    }
});
```

So far the alternative approach is working best for me, but it's not a good way of doing it because when you configure your Router to use the `history` instead of `location.hash` this method won't work anymore.

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the variable in the router?

Comment: I now keep this question up-to-date with the current status

Comment: Seems like this should be in a component now, not so much a controller/view.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your current breadcrumb output I guess you have an error in your router.

The following command should return array with current breadcrumb:

```
App.get('Router.router.currentHandlerInfos');
```

Your router should be nested:

```
this.resource('page 1', function () {
    this.resource('page 2');
});
```

You can use `#linkTo` instead of `a` tag in your breadcrumb, you will get active class for free.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a much simpler solution that I posted to the [Ember discourse](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/router-public-api-for-current-routes-dynamic-breadcrumb/1639/4).

Answer (score 1):

I found a (*Ember-way*) solution to display breadcrumbs. It is based on the router instead of my `location.hash`.

## Infrastructure

First we need to make the infrastructure for the breadcrumbs before we add or remove items from the breadcrumbs array.

### Menu

In my app.js I define a `NavItem`-object. This is a skeleton for all navigatable items. I use it to define my menu-items, but we are also going to use it for the breadcrumbs.

```js
App.NavItem = Em.Object.extend({
    displayText: '',
    routeName: ''
});
// define toplevel menu-items
App.dashboardMenuItem = App.NavItem.create({
    displayText: 'Dashboard',
    routePath: 'dashboard',
    routeName: 'dashboard'
});
App.sitesMenuItem = App.NavItem.create({
    displayText: 'Websites',
    routePath: 'sites.index',
    routeName: 'sites'
});
```

### Controllers

We need a **BreadcrumbsController** to keep the breadcrumbs in a central place

```js
App.BreadcrumbsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: []
});
```

My **ApplicationController** depends on the *BreadcrumbsController*

```js
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['breadcrumbs']
});
```

The **BreadcrumbsView** is a subview of *ApplicationView*

### Views

```js
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    BreadcrumbsView: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'breadcrumbs',

        init: function() {
            this._super();
            this.set('controller', this.get('parentView.controller.controllers.breadcrumbs'));
        },
        gotoRoute: function(e) {
            this.get('controller').transitionToRoute(e.routePath);
        },

        BreadcrumbItemView: Em.View.extend({
            templateName:'breadcrumb-item',
            tagName: 'li'
        })
    })
});
```

### Templates

In my **application**-template I output the breadcrumbsview above the outlet

```
{{view view.BreadcrumbsView}}
{{outlet}}
```

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap so my markup for my **breadcrumbs**-template is

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  {{#each item in controller.content}}
      {{view view.BreadcrumbItemView itemBinding="item"}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The **breadcrumb-item**-template

```
<a href="#" {{action gotoRoute item on="click" target="view.parentView"}}>
  {{item.displayText}}
</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
```

## Routing

We need to respond to the routing in our app to update the breadcrumbs.

When my **SitesRoute** (or any other toplevel route) is activated, we push the NavItem to the Breadcrumbs, but I also want to do that with the rest of my toplevel routes, so I first create a **TopRoute**

```js
App.TopRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        this.controllerFor('menu').setActiveModule(this.get('routeName'));
        var menuItem = app.menuItems.findProperty('routeName',this.get('routeName'));
        this.controllerFor('breadcrumbs').get('content').pushObject(menuItem);
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        var menuItem = app.menuItems.findProperty('routeName',this.get('routeName'));
        this.controllerFor('breadcrumbs').get('content').removeObject(menuItem);
    }
});
```

All my toproutes extend from this route, so the breadcrumbs are automatically updatet

```js
App.SitesRoute = App.TopRoute.extend();
```

For deeper levels it works almost the same, all you have to do is use the `activate` and `deactivate` hooks to push/remove objects from the Breadcrumbs

```js
App.SiteRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        var site = this.modelFor('site');
        this.controllerFor('breadcrumbs').get('content').pushObject(app.NavItem.create({
            displayText: site.get('name'),
            routePath: 'site',
            routeName: this.get('routeName')
        }));
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        var site = this.modelFor('site');
        this.controllerFor('breadcrumbs').get('content').removeAt(1);   
    }
});
```